# Factory many-to-many pivot table attributes

Tags: laravel

I have a `listings` table, a `products` table and a `listing_product` pivot table. The relationships are set up in my `Listing` and `Product` models. My `listing_product` table contains a `position` column.

**Is it possible, using factories, to set the pivot table's `position` according to each model created?**

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#pivot-table-attributes) states:

> If you need to define attributes that should be set on the pivot /
> intermediate table linking the models, you may use the hasAttached
> method. This method accepts an array of pivot table attribute names
> and values as its second argument:

I can do the following:

```
Listing::factory()
    ->hasAttached(
        Product::factory(3),
        ['position' => 1],
    )
    ->create();
```

..but this obviously just sets `position = 1` for each record created in the `listing_product` table, instead of:

- `position = 1` for the first `Product`
- `position = 2` for the second `Product`
- `position = 3` for the third `Product`

Comment: whats the logic of calculating `position`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a factory for the pivot model and use it with a sequence.

```php
$listing = Listing::factory()->create();

ListingProduct::factory()
    ->count(3)
    ->for($listing)
    ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => [
        'position' => $sequence->index + 1,
    ])
    ->create();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#sequences

You can also pass a callback as the second parameter to generate the position based on a variable:

```php
$position = 0;

Listing::factory()
    ->hasAttached(
        Product::factory(3),
        function () use (&$position) {
            return [
                'position' => $position++
            ];
        }
    )
    ->create();
```

Otherwise, you can use the relationship to determine the position but it's going to require more queries:

```php
Listing::factory()
    ->hasAttached(
        Product::factory(3),
        fn ($listing) => [
            'position' => $listing->products()->count() + 1
        ]
    )
    ->create();
```

Comment: Thank you. I've gone with the second solution (: